# How to fix a submit button on a form which is translated by Google?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-translate

**Problem**
I have built an mobile repair website which uses the a plugin called "repair plugin pro". This makes it possible for a customer to select an brand, model and repair and make an appointment. By default the language of the plugin is English, so all the steps for the customer are also in English. My goal was it to have it in Dutch automatically translated by a browser or a plugin. For the translation I use Gtranslate. Everything works in the plugin expect the appointment part. Now when selecting the date this goes well, when selecting the time is doesn't work after its translated. It doesn't save the time so when the customer wants to submit the form is display's in Dutch "selecteer afspraaktijd" or select time.

**Details**
Url of the website: (https://mobilecity.phone-xpert.nl/reparatie-aanmelden)

[google language switcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYbjN.png)
[Schedule date/time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8rZO.png)

**what did I try to solve the problem**
I tried to the add notranslate to the right class of the repair time. I expected that this would solve my issue. Time/date aren't saved, only the date.

The second thing I tried is switching first back to English, than select date/time and switch back to the Dutch translation this seems to work. But ofcourse this wouldn't be a good solution to a customer.

[Switch to English](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMkQT.png)
[Switch to Dutch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtVbA.png)

Comment: Your timeslot `span`s have a click event handler, which calls the function `timeRP_new(this.id)`. I made [a copy of your function](https://pastebin.com/61919ZkB). When that copy is called in the console, with `elem` argument being something like `jQuery(".time-box")[0]`, it works as it should. My guess is that something is interfering with the regular functionality of your `timeRP_new`. I noticed that when the Dutch translation is active, the structure of `span.time-box` changes - `font` elements are added to it, with their own event handlers. That might be causing the issue you're facing.

Comment: If you have access to the JS file holding the `timeRP_new` function, you could edit it (keep a copy of the original close at hand, though), and change the function - just introduce `console.log`s all around to better figure out what's breaking your desired functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I need to find out if I have accces to the JS file, if so I will try what you mentioned @fiddlingAway. I have a clue where the problem is caused as you mentioned it's the translation added. It adds words to the form which are not displayed in English. For example in English it doesn't show time with the word hours, in Dutch it adds the Dutch word for hour 'uur'. I believe this causes conflicts.